# Amazon Marketplace Web Service create inbound shipment NOT_ELIGIBLE_FC_FOR_ITEM, what wrong?

Tags: api, amazon-mws

step 1:

request create inbound shipment plan api.
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_CreateInboundShipmentPlan.html

response:

```
[
//usualy 1-5 plan has been reply,no any one plan contain full of my items.
//the plan 1
{
    "ShipToAddress": {
        ... ignore address detail
    },
    "ShipmentId": "FBA15CQQTFFM",
    "DestinationFulfillmentCenterId": "PHX3",
    "LabelPrepType": "NO_LABEL",
    "Items": [
        //item list, it is alway not full of my provide items.
        {}
    ]
},
//the plan2, and more plan
{},{},...
]
```

step 2:
choose max count items of plan for create inbound shipment.
i cant edit item in this step.
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_CreateInboundShipment.html

step 3:
update inbound shipment plan for add all of item to this plan.
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_UpdateInboundShipment.html

request url: https://mws.amazonservices.com/FulfillmentInboundShipment/2010-10-01

request params:

```
SellerId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SignatureVersion=2
SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
Version=2010-10-01
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentStatus=WORKING
ShipmentId=FBA15CR0QLLR
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipmentName=2018-05-16-AAA
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.Name=Wang%20Jingang
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.AddressLine1=396haozhiyihao
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.AddressLine2=
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.City=Guangzhou
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.DistrictOrCounty=
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.StateOrProvinceCode=Guangdong
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.CountryCode=CN
InboundShipmentHeader.ShipFromAddress.PostalCode=510080
InboundShipmentItems.member.1.SellerSKU=A71231811510311-
InboundShipmentItems.member.1.QuantityShipped=20
InboundShipmentItems.member.2.SellerSKU=A5W3E3112HE0
InboundShipmentItems.member.2.QuantityShipped=80
InboundShipmentItems.member.3.SellerSKU=A71231811540010-
InboundShipmentItems.member.3.QuantityShipped=20
InboundShipmentItems.member.4.SellerSKU=A71231811540011-
InboundShipmentItems.member.4.QuantityShipped=30
InboundShipmentItems.member.5.SellerSKU=A71231811515411-
InboundShipmentItems.member.5.QuantityShipped=20
InboundShipmentItems.member.6.SellerSKU=J8S109225HE90
InboundShipmentItems.member.6.QuantityShipped=10
InboundShipmentItems.member.7.SellerSKU=J8S109225HE92
InboundShipmentItems.member.7.QuantityShipped=33
InboundShipmentItems.member.8.SellerSKU=J8S109225HE93
InboundShipmentItems.member.8.QuantityShipped=10
InboundShipmentItems.member.9.SellerSKU=J8S109225ND90
InboundShipmentItems.member.9.QuantityShipped=8
InboundShipmentItems.member.10.SellerSKU=J8S109225ND91
InboundShipmentItems.member.10.QuantityShipped=12
InboundShipmentItems.member.11.SellerSKU=J8S109225ND92
InboundShipmentItems.member.11.QuantityShipped=17
InboundShipmentItems.member.12.SellerSKU=J8S109225ND93
InboundShipmentItems.member.12.QuantityShipped=14
InboundShipmentItems.member.13.SellerSKU=J8S109225ND94
InboundShipmentItems.member.13.QuantityShipped=5
InboundShipmentItems.member.14.SellerSKU=J8S109225QC90
InboundShipmentItems.member.14.QuantityShipped=10
InboundShipmentItems.member.15.SellerSKU=J8S109225QC91
InboundShipmentItems.member.15.QuantityShipped=5
InboundShipmentItems.member.16.SellerSKU=J8S109225QC92
InboundShipmentItems.member.16.QuantityShipped=9
InboundShipmentHeader.AreCasesRequired=false
Action=UpdateInboundShipment
Timestamp=2018-05-18T13%3A08%3A04%2B08%3A00
Signature=LCFu1NoX1QnENH1oCFEbwsXy1JVh7QNjpe2enGj258Q%3D
```

sometime success.
sometime fail, and tell me [skuType=MSKU, sku=..., reason=NOT_ELIGIBLE_FC_FOR_ITEM.]

do not change anything.
replicated 1-3. 
sometime success.
sometime fail, and tell me [skuType=MSKU, sku=..., reason=NOT_ELIGIBLE_FC_FOR_ITEM.]

imcomprehensible it is, sku maybe not equal with last time. it is random, maybe one, mabe two.

can you tell me waht wrong?

HOW CAN I TO DO, MAKE ALL ITEMS IN ONE PLAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the sam error before, I found a ref.:

https://help.scanpower.com/support/solutions/articles/11000037578-what-does-the-not-eligible-fc-for-item-error-mean-

FYI, sure, I have a SKU, when creating inbound shipment, to old account, it's OK, but to new account, API will reponse the error you said.

> Unfortunately, this error is coming directly from Amazon. There is a product in your shipment that is causing a conflict with the inbound shipping and/or the fulfillment center, but Amazon does not give us any indication as to the specific issue.
>
> We have contacted Amazon and they suggest each seller experiencing this issue contact Seller Support for more information on the error.  Please let them know that you are listing said item(s) via their MWS API and are receiving the following message: (insert the text of YOUR SPECIFIC ERROR MSG HERE what you see below is an example)
>
> Invalid Items found - ShipmentId [FBA53HXYFX] MerchantCustomerId [A2WOJIKNACJWE4] InvalidItems[ (skuType=MSKU, sku=2016-11-30-B0006SGYS8-1099, reason=NOT_ELIGIBLE_FC_FOR_ITEM)]Shipment Id: FBA53HXYFXRequest Id: fb04a1f9-721f-4be3-a9c7-ba4063c13f69